# Ransack / Rails 6 : PG::UndefinedTable for a query through a belongs_to

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ransack

I can't chain a where and a Ransack query, I get a `PG::UndefinedTable` error. I'm using Rails 6.1.3 and Ransack 2.4.2.

I have seen this issue : https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1119 where everybody agrees that the problem has been fixed with the upgrade to rails 6.1. Sadly, not for my case.

My models looks like this :

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :slot
end 

class Slot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
end
```

This query

```
Appointment.joins(slot: [:place])
           .where('slot.date' => Date.today)
           .ransack(slot_place_id_eq: 2)
           .result
```

returns this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "slots")
LINE 1: ...ointments"."slot_id" WHERE "slot"."date" = $1 AND "slots"."p...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "slot".
```

The generated query is the following, and indeed, `slots.place_id` can't work for a belongs_to.

```
SELECT appointments.*
FROM appointments 
INNER JOIN slots slot ON slot.id = appointments.slot_id
INNER JOIN places ON places.id = slot.place_id
WHERE slot.date = '2021-06-30' AND slots.place_id = 2
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this : it was a different issue, with the same error message than the other one.

This :

```
.where('slot.date' => Date.today)
```

is supposed to be this :

```
.where('slots.date' => Date.today)
```

Two hour of research, 10 minutes to write a SO question, finding the solution by yourself 30 seconds after clicking publish....

Comment: It was a nicely formatted question, I'm almost disappointed that the solution was that easy :(